# Does Gunicorn serve Flask static files by default?

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, static, docker-compose

Having some trouble understanding how Gunicorn is serving my static files. It's serving them even though NGINX isn't running and I haven't setup a route/function to serve static files...?

I am running a Flask App from docker-compose. I was trying to configure Nginx to act as a reverse proxy to forward requests to Gunicorn and serve static files. However, after much troubleshooting I couldn't get it to forward on the requests. I would just get nothing looking at localhost:80, which in turn is mapped to nginx:80, which is listening to zigweb:8000. I tried a couple of different mapped ports on host, 5000, 1337, etc, but no dice.

I could only get my Flask app to run if I mapped port 8000:8000 on my zigweb (my flask app), so I could connect to gunicorn directly. The weird thing is, when I now connect to localhost:8000 this way, static IS being served, even though I literally pulled NGINX out of the docker-compose...?

I've tried killing every single other docker container / image, but it feels like something is off? How can Gunicorn serve static files if I've not told Flask/Gunicorn to do that?

**EDIT 1**
When I run `docker container ls` I do not get back an NGINX container, and can confirm that when I go to localhost:8000 I am seeing my web app, and the static css is being served.

This link works:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css

**EDIT 2**

I should add - a while back I played with Fast API docker. I installed it, and it was some mammoth docker file. Every so often, after I've run docker-compose up, if I go to localhost/ap or http://localhost/login I would get the Fast API login page. I absolutely could not figure out how and where that was being served from.

Is there a mystery NGINX docker container running undetected? How can I kill it?
I'm on Windows 10.

```
dc9aac2902b6        zig-dock_zigweb     "/usr/local/bin/guni…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp             zig-dock_zigweb_1
76f8d8ed7f23        postgres:11         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 minutes ago       Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             zig-dock_postgres_1
85fab7516d9a        zig-dock_zigbot     "python main.py"         37 minutes ago       Up About a minute   80/tcp                             zig-dock_zigbot_1
d35851c2ae20        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 minutes ago       Up About a minute   6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6739->6739/tcp   zig-dock_redis_db_1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  zigweb:
    restart: always
    build: ./zigweb
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    volumes:
      - web-data:/usr/src/zigweb/app/static
    env_file:
      - zigweb/.envdocker
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

  zigbot:
    restart: always
    build: ./zigbot
    expose:
      - "80"
    env_file:
      - zigbot/.envdocker
    command: "python main.py"

  data:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: "true"

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    command: postgres -c listen_addresses='*'

  redis_db:
    restart: always
    image: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    volumes:
      - reddis-data:/data
    ports:
      - "6739:6739"


volumes:
  db-data:
  web-data:
  reddis-data:
```

Comment: Did you give static_url while creating flask app?

Comment: No I didn't. There's no reference at all to static in my Flask app.